# Sneaky font substitution and font missing from only some apps' font menus

Tags: fonts, microsoft-word-2011, iwork-pages, typography, opentype

I have a bit of a head-scratcher. I'm attempting to use DINPro in both Pages 5.6.2 and Word 2011 on my rMBP 15" running El Cap 10.11.6. I'm seeing DINPro in Pages, but Abel in Word.

At first I didn't even see DINPro in the Word font menu, but I persisted, and tried putting in the font names directly (“DINPro-Regular” and “DINPro-Bold”) in Word's font field. I don't get DIN when I do this, but rather I get Abel Regular/Bold. [See this imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGGkP.jpg)

I'm not sure if this is some sort of sneaky font substitution based on metrics, or just a bug (maybe Abel is alphabetically first and Word chooses it when it can't find a font you put in?). I also can't figure out why the DINPro Regular and Bold fonts aren't showing up in the Word font menu. They are .otf files installed in my ~/Library/Fonts folder. I can provide more font file details if needed.